# Regex is unable to use same character for two matches

Tags: regex, preg-replace

In the regex below, I want to match all cases of "ac" when it is contained between two slashes. The first one matches, but the second one does not because the middle slash is being used for the first match. Any way to force the second "ac" to match as well?

https://regex101.com/r/WxTFJI/2

Below is what i have tried

```
([\/])ac([\/])
```

My test string is

```
/ac/ac/
```

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the help! Good to know about including info in the post itself - will make sure to do that in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reason why `(\/)ac(\/)` does not match the second ac is because the second **/ac/** has already been captured remaining with **ac/** but as per your question you just want the `ac` without the slashes. if so then

```
(?<=\/)ac(?=\/)
```